# How to implement Slider Bar and 3d pie chart for ASP.net MVC4 Razor Template?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am developing an application using ASP.net MVC4.
My usecase has a requirement to implement  slider bar whose change in values should affect a 3d pie chart. I couldn't find sample examples online or implementation. 
I would be a great help if somebody could provide an insight on this. 
Looking forward to hear from you all ASAP.
Thanks in advance:

Following are the details about how a slider and pie chart should look like with MVC4 ASP.net C# implementation.

http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Slider/Slider.aspx
http://www.i36.tinypic.com/2wduhkn.png

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Jquery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) for the slider and a [HighCharts pie chart](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-gradient) for the graphic.