# How to use Ajax Control Toolkit in Razor MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How to use [Ajax Slider](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Slider/Slider.aspx) from Ajax Control toolkit in ASP.net MVC4 Razor template application?

Comment: The AJAX control toolkit is truly meant for a WebForms application (as it uses page controls) and not for MVC.  There are slider controls for JQuery (JQuery UI for example) that will work fine with MVC and most likely be more cross-browser compatible.

Comment: @Tommy Thank you so much for your information. It's helpful. I really appreciate. Is there any other possible way I can do it server side? Using Ajax call?This is my real usecase.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12175036/how-to-implement-slider-bar-and-3d-pie-chart-for-asp-net-mvc4-razor-template. Would be really helpful if you could give your thoughts on this.

Answer (score 3):

Ajax toolkit doesn't work with MVC because it was built for WebForms. So You have to use alternates for that purpose like "JQUERY".

Answer (score 2):

You are unable to use AJAX Control Toolkit for MVC 4 because it is a set of User controls build in Web Forms and only compatible with ASP.NET Web Forms. jQuery, DevExpress, Infragistics and other toolkits are available for MVC.

Check the links here: [Dev Express Tool Kit For Asp.Net MVC 4](http://mvc.devexpress.com/)